Función ascii en PSeInt
Tengo este código que pretende dar el código ascii un caracter introducido por usuario.
Estoy usando arreglos en base 0
El programa compila pero da resultado incorrecto cuando la letra ingresada es minúscula
Ejemplo:

Ingrese un carácter:
a
Resultado esperado: Escribir "El código ASCII de a es: 97
Resultado obtenido:El código ASCII de a es: 65

Funcion retorno <- Ascii(caracter)
    Definir codigoAscii, retorno, i Como Enteros;
    codigoAscii <- 0;  //
    // PSeInt no maneja ASCII directamente, así que necesitamos "engañarlo" 
    // comparando con una cadena que contenga el alfabeto
    Definir alfabeto Como Cadena;
    alfabeto <- "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    
    // Buscar el carácter en mayúsculas dentro del alfabeto
    Para i <- 0 Hasta Longitud(alfabeto) Hacer
        Si Subcadena(alfabeto, i, i) = Mayusculas(caracter) Entonces
            codigoAscii <- i + 65; // 65 es el código ASCII de 'A'
            Retorno <- codigoAscii;
        FinSi
    FinPara
    
    // Si no se encontró en mayúsculas, buscar en minúsculas
    Si codigoAscii = 0 Entonces // Significa que no se encontró en mayúsculas
        Para i <- 0 Hasta Longitud(alfabeto) Hacer
            Si Subcadena(alfabeto, i, i) = Minusculas(caracter) Entonces
                codigoAscii <- i + 97; // 97 es el código ASCII de 'a'
                Retorno <- codigoAscii;
            FinSi
        FinPara
    FinSi
    
    // Si aún no se encontró, es un carácter especial o no alfabético
    Si codigoAscii = 0 Entonces
        Escribir "El carácter ingresado no es una letra.";
    FinSi
    
FinFuncion

// Ejemplo de uso
Proceso Principal
    Definir caracter Como Caracter;
    Definir valorAscii Como Entero;
    
    Escribir "Ingrese un carácter: ";
    Leer caracter;
    
    valorAscii <- Ascii(caracter);
    
    Si valorAscii <> 0 Entonces
        Escribir "El código ASCII de " , caracter , " es: ", valorAscii;
    SiNo
        Escribir "El carácter no es una letra";
   FinSi
    
FinProceso


El comentario anterior mío fue erróneo, con este código debería funcionar correctamente :), en la segunda condicional también deberías convertir la variable 'alfabeto' en Minusculas.
    Funcion retorno <- Ascii(caracter)
        Definir codigoAscii, retorno, i Como Enteros;
        codigoAscii <- 0; //
        // PSeInt no maneja ASCII directamente, así que necesitamos "engañarlo" 
        // comparando con una cadena que contenga el alfabeto
        Definir alfabeto Como Cadena;
        alfabeto <- "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        
        // Buscar el carácter en mayúsculas dentro del alfabeto
        Para i <- 0 Hasta Longitud(alfabeto) Hacer
            Si Subcadena(alfabeto, i, i) = caracter Entonces
                codigoAscii <- i + 65; // 65 es el código ASCII de 'A'
                Retorno <- codigoAscii;
            FinSi
        FinPara
        
    // Si no se encontró en mayúsculas, buscar en minúsculas
    Si codigoAscii = 0 Entonces // Significa que no se encontró en mayúsculas
        Para i <- 0 Hasta Longitud(alfabeto) Hacer
            Si Subcadena(Minusculas(alfabeto), i, i) = caracter Entonces
                codigoAscii <- i + 97; // 97 es el código ASCII de 'a'
                Retorno <- codigoAscii;
            FinSi
        FinPara
    FinSi
    
    // Si aún no se encontró, es un carácter especial o no alfabético
    Si codigoAscii = 0 Entonces
        Escribir "El carácter ingresado no es una letra.";
    FinSi
FinFuncion

// Ejemplo de uso
Proceso Principal
    Definir caracter Como Caracter;
    Definir valorAscii Como Entero;
    
    Escribir "Ingrese un carácter: ";
    Leer caracter;
    
    valorAscii <- Ascii(caracter);
    
    Si valorAscii <> 0 Entonces
        Escribir "El código ASCII de " , caracter , " es: ", valorAscii;
    SiNo
        Escribir "El carácter no es una letra";
    FinSi

FinProceso

No tiene ningun sentido hacer 2 iteraciones sobre la cadena, alcanza con una sola. Los dos si podrian estar en el mismo Para...

Es mas, Si codigoAscii = 0 Entonces no tiene sentido, salvo que pseint no retorno de la funcion al hacer retorno. Si no, cuando llegamos a ese punto, no era mayuscula...
